# Windows starts and immediately log off

Tags: windows-xp, logoff

I am with Windows XP.Yesterday I downloaded and installed a software and since then avast was blocking attempts to open some links.The links contained some malware.They came from file ,named xzobya.exe and this file tried to open those links every 10 minutes.But avast didn't find virus in the file. 
I think that I have some virus but Avast didn't detect nothing. 
So when I started the computer today ,I log into the windows and my background showed.After that - computer log off and shows some black screen. 
I received 1000000a error yesterday ,too. 
What should I do?I don't want to reinstall Windows but if it's necessary...

PS.
I tried last known good configuration and now the black screen has gone.Just constantly logging off.
In safe mode is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply its borked.

Reinstalling windows is the BEST, most troublefree alternative - it should be the quickest and most likely should work

One alternative is booting from the installer cd into the recovery environment and running sfc /scannow - this will check your system files against what's on the CD and replace damaged ones

The other is to do a repair install - an install over the partition without reformatting - this reinstalls key system files, but may break some software.

Of the three, reinstalling is your BEST option

Comment: Thank You but I have really important information.How to save it?Maybe some live cd?What would You recommend me?

Comment: the latter two options SHOULD work without wiping your whole disk. Nearly any livecd will do for file recovery - you may just have to forcemount the windows disk. I usually use any ubuntu disk i have lying around for such things